# SSH command in Bash script not running

Tags: php, bash, shell, ssh, shell-exec

I have an SSH command in a bash script to connect and list a server's home files but when I run it from my PHP script I get no output. I have setup an SSH key between my computer and the server. Running the bash script in the terminal works but for some reason I can't get it to be called from the PHP script.

Here is the bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh user@location "ls"
```

And the PHP script which calls the script:

```
<?php
chdir('/opt/lampp/htdocs');
echo shell_exec('./run');
?>
```

Comment: Are you running the PHP script in the same terminal session as the bash script?

Comment: Change it to `echo shell_exec('./run 2>&1');` so you see error messages.

Comment: Hi, my PHP script is located on my local server (lampp) so I just execute the  Bash script from there. This is the error message I get when I run that command you suggested:
_ssh: /opt/lampp/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: version `OPENSSL_1.0.1' not found (required by ssh)_

Comment: It sounds like your `.profile` adds the OpenSSL directory to your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but this isn't done for the webserver process. Also, the webserver won't use your SSH key -- have you added the key to the webserver user's `.ssh` directory?

Comment: Ah right ok I see. No I don't know how to add the key to the user's `.ssh` directory :( I followed this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2) to set up the keys between my computer and the server. What would I have to do differently?

Comment: Create a new key using the same procedure but a different filename. Copy the private key to the user's `.ssh` directory, add the public key to the server's `authorized_keys` file. Change the user's `.ssh/config` so it uses that key file for this server.

Comment: Ok thanks for that guidance Barmar. When you say copy the private key to the user's `.ssh` directory.. which directory is that? where would you typically find it? Also, I'd change the user's `.ssh/config` on the server side?

Comment: Just to add, I can't seem to find the `.ssh/config` directory on the server side? I just have the `.ssh` directory and its files.

Comment: If the webserver runs as user apache, you would copy to `~apache/.ssh`. The the `.ssh/config` that needs to be edited is on the client, it needs `Host location` followed by `IdentityFile privatekeyfilename`. The only change on the server is to add this new public key to `user`'s `.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Comment: I think maybe you need to learn the basics of how SSH public key authentication works. If you understand the principles the rest follows naturally. I'm not going to try to teach an SSH class here in the comments.

Comment: No I appreciate that Barmar, I value the help you've given me. It's just that all of this is new to me and I can't find any other resources online to help me solve this problem :(

Comment: Can I ask one question.. is this whole thing even possible using XAMPP local server?

Comment: I don't see why that should make a difference.

Comment: Only reason why I'm asking is that I can't find the `~apache/.ssh` directory in my XAMPP server files.

Comment: You have to create it. Apache doesn't normally use SSH, so it doesn't have a need for that directory by default.

Comment: Aahh I see, so I'd create that directory along with `/config` within it in the root directory of XAMPP?

Comment: Yes. Just like you had to do when you first created your own `.ssh` directory.

Comment: I've tried all of the above and no change :/ can I just double check with you though.. I added the fields host, HostName and IdentityFile to the config file. The config and private key files are both located in the directory `~apache/.ssh`. Is that correct?

Comment: Make sure the permissions are all correct on the files. They should only be readable by the apache user. Are you capturing error messages like I suggested above?

Answer (score 0):

While running from php script 'Apache' is the user, just check 'Apache' user have execute permissions in this folder.